# Is there a command to convert administrator account to standard user account windows via a command line

Tags: windows, command-line, java, administrator, standard-user

Is there a command to convert an Administrator account into a standard/local user in windows via command line which can be implemented in a Java code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: We need a bit more detail in the question before we can service this. What operating system? Why Java? To what end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> convert an Administrator account into a standard/local user in windows via command line

Remove the user from the Local Administrators group.

`Net localgroup Administrators <UserName> /delete` should accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply deleting the user from the administrator group leaves the account as "guest" Assuming you want this account to be a standard user, issue this command after removing from the administrator group.

net localgroup Users "user" /add

Comment: All users are part of User user group by default.  So an Administrator user would be part of two user groups by default.  This means your command isn't required.